# Errors occur in kernel entry after enabling MMU of Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, kernel, raspberry-pi2, mmu

I have encountered some problems when transplanting MIT's JOS to Raspberry Pi 2. I've known kernel entry should be 0x8000 according to some materials, and I modified the .ld file for kernel to set the virtual address at 0xF0008000. To enable the MMU I set up a simple 1L Section Table for the MMU and mapped the 16MB from 0x00000000 to its original address and mapped 16MB from 0xF0000000 to 16MB from physical address of 0x00000000. I also mapped the 1MB at GPIO_BASE to enable basic I/O. The kernel works well on the QEMU for RPI2 but won't work after enabling MMU on real raspberry pi 2. I tried to disable MMU and set both virtual and physical address of kernel to 0x8000 and it worked on the board. But I can't figure out how to make it work with MMU enabled.

I also have a question about domains. If I set the ACL of domain 0 to 01(Client) to enable AP checking of pages, every LDR after enabling MMU just gets stuck. It also won't work on QEMU. I've already set the APs of pages.
(This bug is fixed by removing the NX bits...The tutorial I saw told me it should be set. What a shame... But the first problem is still there.)

The entry.S of the kernel

```
/* See COPYRIGHT for copyright information. */

#include <inc/mmu.h>
#include <inc/memlayout.h>

# Shift Right Logical 
#define SRL(val, shamt)     (((val) >> (shamt)) & ~(-1 << (32 - (shamt))))


###################################################################
# The kernel (this code) is linked at address ~(KERNBASE + 1 Meg), 
# but the bootloader loads it at address ~1 Meg.
#   
# RELOC(x) maps a symbol x from its link address to its actual
# location in physical memory (its load address).    
###################################################################

#define RELOC(x) ((x) - KERNBASE)

###################################################################
# entry point
###################################################################



.section ".text"


# '_start' specifies the ELF entry point.  Since we haven't set up
# virtual memory when the bootloader enters this code, we need the
# bootloader to jump to the *physical* address of the entry point.
.globl      _start
_start = RELOC(entry)

.globl entry
entry:
cps #0x13       /* Change to supervisor (SVC) mode */

ldr r0, =bootstacktop
mov sp, r0

mov r0, #0
mcr p15, 0, r0, c2, c0, 2
/* Set Domain 0 ACL to "Manager"
 * See ARM1176JZF-S manual, 3-64
 * Every mapped section/page is in domain 0
 */
mov r0, #3
mcr p15, 0, r0, c3, c0, 0
/* Read control register to r0 */
mrc p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0
/* Turn on MMU */
orr r0, r0, #1
/* Write value back to control register */
mcr p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0


ldr lr, =pi_init
bx lr

.data
###################################################################
# boot stack
###################################################################
# force page alignment
    .p2align    PGSHIFT     
    .globl      bootstack
bootstack:
    .space      KSTKSIZE
    .globl      bootstacktop   
bootstacktop:
```

kernel.ld

```
/* Simple linker script for the JOS kernel.
   See the GNU ld 'info' manual ("info ld") to learn the syntax. */

ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
    /* Link the kernel at this address: "." means the current address */
    . = 0xF0008000;

    /* AT(...) gives the load address of this section, which tells
       the boot loader where to load the kernel in physical memory */
    .text : AT(0x8000) {
        *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    }

    PROVIDE(etext = .); /* Define the 'etext' symbol to this value */

    .rodata : {
        *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*)
    }

    /* Include debugging information in kernel memory */
    .stab : {
        PROVIDE(__STAB_BEGIN__ = .);
        *(.stab);
        PROVIDE(__STAB_END__ = .);
        BYTE(0)     /* Force the linker to allocate space
                   for this section */
    }

    .stabstr : {
        PROVIDE(__STABSTR_BEGIN__ = .);
        *(.stabstr);
        PROVIDE(__STABSTR_END__ = .);
        BYTE(0)     /* Force the linker to allocate space
                   for this section */
    }

    /* Adjust the address for the data segment to the next page */
    . = ALIGN(0x1000);

    /* The data segment */
    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }

    PROVIDE(edata = .);

    .bss : {
        *(.bss)
    }

    PROVIDE(end = .);

    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.eh_frame .note.GNU-stack)
    }
}
```

Page directory(section directory)

```
__attribute__((__aligned__(NPTENTRIES << 2)))
pde_t entry_pgdir[NPTENTRIES] = {
    // Map VA's [0, 16MB) to PA's [0, 16MB)
    [0] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 0, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [1] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 1, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [2] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 2, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [3] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 3, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [4] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 4, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [5] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 5, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [6] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 6, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [7] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 7, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [8] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 8, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [9] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 9, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [10] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 10, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [11] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 11, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [12] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 12, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [13] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 13, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [14] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 14, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [15] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 15, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,

    // Map VA's [GPIO_BASE, GPIO_BASE+1MB) to [GPIO_BASE, GPIO_BASE+1MB)
    [(GPIO_BASE>>PTXSHIFT) + 0] = GPIO_BASE | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,

    // Map VA's [KERNBASE, KERNBASE+16MB) to PA's [0, 16MB)
    [(KERNBASE>>PTXSHIFT) + 0] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 0, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [(KERNBASE>>PTXSHIFT) + 1] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 1, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [(KERNBASE>>PTXSHIFT) + 2] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 2, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [(KERNBASE>>PTXSHIFT) + 3] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 3, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [(KERNBASE>>PTXSHIFT) + 4] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 4, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [(KERNBASE>>PTXSHIFT) + 5] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 5, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [(KERNBASE>>PTXSHIFT) + 6] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 6, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [(KERNBASE>>PTXSHIFT) + 7] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 7, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [(KERNBASE>>PTXSHIFT) + 8] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 8, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [(KERNBASE>>PTXSHIFT) + 9] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 9, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [(KERNBASE>>PTXSHIFT) + 10] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 10, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [(KERNBASE>>PTXSHIFT) + 11] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 11, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [(KERNBASE>>PTXSHIFT) + 12] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 12, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [(KERNBASE>>PTXSHIFT) + 13] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 13, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [(KERNBASE>>PTXSHIFT) + 14] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 14, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO,
    [(KERNBASE>>PTXSHIFT) + 15] = (unsigned)PGADDR(0, 15, 0) | PTE_P | PTE_SWO
};
```

Some macros

```
// +--------31-20---------+-19-16---15----14-12---+-11-10-+9+----8-5---+4+3+2+1+0+
// |      Section base    |  Zeros |APX|  ZEROS   |  AP   | | Domain   |X|C|B| | |
// |        address       |        |   |          |       |0|          |N| | |1|0|
// +----------------------+--------+---+----------+-------+-+----------+-+-+-+-+-+
// Page table/directory entry flags.
#define PTE_AP_X    0x8C00  // AP and APX bits
#define PTE_P       0x0002  // Present
#define PTE_NX      0x0010  // Execute never
#define PTE_C       0x0008  // Cacheable
#define PTE_B       0x0004  // Bufferable
#define PTE_SRUR    0x8C00  // Superviser reads only & user reads only
#define PTE_SRO     0x8400  // Superviser reads only
#define PTE_SWO     0x0400  // Superviser writes only
#define PTE_SWUR    0x0800  // Superviser writes & user reads
#define PTE_SWUW    0x8C00  // Superviser writes & user writes
```

Comment: _"I've already set the APs of pages"_ - to what? Those macros are hardly self-explanatory...

Comment: The APs are set to 01 as "supervisor writes only".

Answer (score 0):

Given that it works on an emulator but not on hardware, I'd strongly suspect that the complete lack of any of the architecturally-required cache/TLB maintenance is significant.

The architecture makes no promises about what's in the caches/TLBs out of reset, and even if it did you don't know what the bootloader might have left hanging around, so it's up to you to make sure there are no stale entries (or uninitialised junk which just happens to look valid) present before turning the MMU on:

```
mcr p15, 0, r0, c8, c7, 0  @ TLBIALL: invalidate all TLBs
mcr p15, 0, r0, c7, c5, 1  @ ICIALLU: invalidate instruction cache
dsb                        @ ensure invalidations have completed
```

Data cache invalidation is considerably more involved, but since you have everything non-cacheable here I'm going to hope that that's a problem for the future, and just [wave in the general direction of some existing code](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/cache-v7.S).